# Smarty cut string to add dots

Tags: php, smarty

I have this code:

```
{if $data|@count gt 0}

  {section name=field loop=$data}

    {$data[field].description|substr:0:120}...

    <hr/>

  {/section}

{/if}
```

It shows `abc123 abc123 a...`.

How can I get the words not to cut?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Why don't you use the truncate modifier http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifier.truncate

You can set it not to break on a word.